# Solving a Third order Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve:

$$
v_{yyy} + vv_y + \frac{1}{3}yv_y + \frac{2}{3}v = 0
$$

where $v$ is a function of $y$.

Is there a way to reduce it to a solveable second order equation?

This equation is found when looking for a solution along one of the Lie Symmetries of the ODE:
$$
u_t - uu_x - u_{xxx}
$$

From what I have read, there is a transformation discovered by Miura, for the equation.  We are to set:
$$
v = \frac{-1}{6}w^2 + \frac{dw}{dy}
$$

I now need to find $v_{yyy}, v_y$ in terms of $\frac{dw}{dy}$ and sub that into the initial equation.

I have:
\begin{align}
v &= \frac{-1}{6}w^2 + w_y\\
v_y &= \frac{-1}{3}w w_y + w_{yy}\\
v_{yy} &= \frac{-1}{3}(w_y)^2 - \frac{1}{3}ww_{yy}+w_{yyy}\\
v_{yyy}&=-w_yw_{yy}-\frac{1}{3}w_yw_{yy}-\frac{1}{3}ww_{yyy}+w_{yyyy}\\
\end{align}

When I substitute this into the third order equation I get:

$$
w_{yyyy}-\frac{1}{3}ww_{yyy}-\frac{1}{3}w(w_y)^2-\frac{1}{6}w^2w_{yy}+\frac{1}{18}w^3w_y+\frac{1}{3}yw_{yy}-\frac{1}{9}yww_y+\frac{2}{3}w_y-\frac{1}{9}w^2=0
$$

According to what I have read, this can now be factored and then integrated.
The example I am following and using to apply to my equation is on page 195 of Olver.

In following the examplefrom Olver and applying the technique to my equation I get:
$$
(D_y - \frac{1}{3}w)(w_{yyy} - \frac{1}{6}w^2w_y + \frac{1}{3}yw_y + \frac{1}{3}w) = 0
$$

Now I want to integrate and solve:
$$
w_{yyy} - \frac{1}{6}w^2w_y + \frac{1}{3}yw_y + \frac{1}{3}w = 0
$$

When I integrate I get:
$$
w_{yy} - \frac{1}{18}w^3 + \frac{1}{3}yw + k = 0
$$

How do I go about solving this second order NonLinear Differential Equation?

The example in Olver, which differs slightly from my equation, has a positive $w^3$ term and states that the equation is a from of the Second Painleve Transcendent.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions ?

Comment: there are no boundary conditions

Comment: If your equation was
\begin{align}
v_{yyy}+vv_y+\frac{1}{3}yv_y+\frac{1}{3}v=0,
\end{align} 
you could integrate directly,
\begin{align}
v_{yy}+\frac{1}{2}v^2+\frac{1}{3}yv=c.
\end{align}
Maybe you're lucky and made a math error deriving your equation or copied it wrong?

Comment: @Eli sadly, no, I have not made an error. The equation I put in is indeed the one that I need to solve.

Comment: @sarahjamal All the tricks I throw at it almost work and then don’t, perhaps you’ll find a super neat one that does the job!

Comment: @Eli any idea how JJacquelin got the solution?  What "tricks" are you using, I'm looking for how to solve third order equations, and really can't find anything that satisfies the format given.

Comment: @sarahjamal While I certainly don’t have the expertise that JJacquelin has, it’s safe to say they got those answers via guess and check or noticing a pattern of sorts. My ‘tricks’ are usually just seeing if I can integrate it right away, maybe it’s an exact differential with a necessary integration constant, perhaps adding an integrable term makes it exact, substituting $y(x)$ and perhaps assuming some relation simplifies the equation, or making a few different $v(u(y))$ substitutions. I was so sure substituting $v=u_y$ would work, but the problem it solved only moved elsewhere. Alas.

Comment: Eli is right. This was not a super-trick. Just looking for solutions on the form $v=ay^b$. This leads to three solutions : $(a=0,b)$ , $(a=-1,b=1)$ and $(a=-12,b=-2)$.

Comment: If the the question comes from an academic exercise probably there is a typo in the PDE. Where the equation is comming from ?

Comment: @Eli I have found part of a way towards a solution, and added that to the post. Perhaps you or JJacquelin could help take it to the finish line?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not seem inspired.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sadly you're right. Maybe The work I put in now would help reach a conclusion.

Comment: @sarahjamal your book gave you the answer. The equation is a second Painleve Transcendent, which from my skimming seems to be an active area of research. Check out the wikipedia page <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_transcendents> or this page <https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2019/006/> for some references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you meant by *solving the equation*. To clarify, I will write each part separately.  (Let me know if any parts are not clear.)

First, let me first label your equation:
$$ w_{yy}=\frac{w^3}{18} -\frac{1}{3}yw - k. \qquad (1)$$

1. *How can we recognize Equation (1) as the second Painlevé equation?*

Equation (1) can be transformed to the standard form for the second Painlevé equation by taking new variables:
$$  w(y)=\mu p(t),\quad y=\nu\,t, $$
where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are constant parameters, which leads to
$$ \frac{\mu}{\nu^2} p_{tt}=\frac{\mu^3}{18} p^3-\frac{\mu\nu}{3} t p -k .$$
Dividing by $\mu/\nu^2$, we arrive at
$$ p_{tt}=\frac{\mu^2\nu^2}{18} p^3 -\frac{\nu^3}{3} t p - \frac{k\nu^2}{\mu}.$$

Compare this with the standard form of the second Painlevé equation:
$$ {\rm PII:} \quad p_{tt}= 2 p^3 + t p +\alpha.$$
We get this form if we take
$$ \nu^3=-3, \ \mu^2\nu^2=36, \alpha=-k\nu^2/\mu ,$$
which is achieved by
$$\nu=-3^{1/3}, \mu=-6/3^{1/3}, \alpha=k /2.$$

2. *How can we solve the second Painlevé equation in general?*

This is a difficult question because general solutions of PII are *higher transcendental* functions that are known not be expressible in terms of a finite number of earlier known functions, like polynomials of $t$, or rational functions of $t$, exponentials, trigonometric, or other classical functions like hypergeometric functions of $t$.

So the best  we can do is to give a new name to a solution of PII and write that down as an answer to your question. To identify a solution, we need to provide an initial or a boundary value. For example, a famous higher transcendental solution called the Hastings-McLeod solution is defined as a solution of PII for $\alpha=0$ that vanishes (faster than $\exp{-(2t^{3/2}/3)}$) as $t\to +\infty$.

3. *Are there special solutions of the second Painlevé equation that can be expressed explicitly in terms of familiar functions?*

Yes, but only if $\alpha$ takes on special values. The starting point for finding these solutions is by observation. Consider $\alpha=0$, it is easy to see that the identically zero function $p(t)\equiv 0$ is a solution.

To get more solutions, we use a well known transformation between solutions of different copies of PII.  Suppose $p_\alpha(t)$ is a solution of PII with parameter $\alpha$, while $p_{\alpha\pm 1}(t)$ is a solution of PII with parameter $\alpha\pm 1$. Then the transformation (called a Bäcklund transformation) is given by
$$p_{\alpha\pm 1}=-p_\alpha-\frac{2\alpha\pm 1}{2p _\alpha^2\pm 2p_\alpha’+t},$$
Where prime refers to a $t$-derivative.
If we apply this transformation to $p_0(t)=0$, we get
$$p_{\pm 1}=\mp\,\frac{1}{t}.$$
Repeated application gives an infinite sequence of rational functions that solve PII with integer values of $\alpha$. (Note that these are not general solutions because no free parameters (or integration constants) arise in these solutions.)

Similarly, there is an infinite sequence of solutions of PII with half-integer values of $\alpha$ given by Airy functions. Take a look at
[Chapter 32 of DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/32.10) for more detail.

I hope these give a glimpse of some of the very rich properties of the equation you asked about.

Answer (score 2):

A particular solution is :
$$v=-\frac{12}{y^2}$$

Of course this is far to be the general solution. Hopping that help.

Obviously $\quad v=0\quad$ and $\quad v=-y\quad$ are  trivial solutions.

Comment: how do I arrive at this solution?